# SQL Server 2005 not connect

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

In my online database I take the database in offline and close the SQL Server.

Now my database shows an error

> *login failed*

but login Id and password are correct and not connect to database

Please help me to connect to it again, I use SQL Server 2005.

Comment: This is not a "question". If you take the time to formulate it as such, add more information about how do you connect to the DB, what commands/functions are you issuing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to connect to the database itself when it's offline, but should still be able to connect to the master database. The question isn't clear on how you're trying to access it but for example:

```
USE [master] 
GO 
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET ONLINE 
GO
```

Or from SQL Server Management Studio you should still be able to connect to the database server itself and execute the second command under the context of the master database.